# Azure,Android,Raspberry pi

Tags: android, raspberry-pi3, azure-iot-hub

As I am new to this profession, I wanted the LED on the raspberry pi to be controlled using the android phone through AZURE IOT hub. How can I connect both the hardware and android application to the single lot hub?
which one should we use services bus or event hub?

Comment: What's the operating system running on your Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Raspbian jessie

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following two methods:

1. Use service bus:

For Raspbian side, you can follow "[Using Service Bus from Python with AMQP 1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-amqp-python)".

For Android side, you can follow "[Using Service Bus / EventHub from Android devices](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shacorn/2015/01/07/using-service-bus-eventhub-from-android-devices/)"

2. Use event hub:

For Raspbian side, you can follow "[Microsoft Azure IoT SDKs and libraries for C](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/tree/76906dc5fcb38eb3d2c67b670f638ed8965e502d)".

For Android side, you can follow "[Using the Azure IoT SDK in Android](https://dzone.com/articles/using-azure-iot-sdk-in-android)"

Comment: I Tried,But I am not Understanding Anything.so will you please help me to solve this problem?